# MDDatatable filling up with database info

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to use my data base info to use in my MDDataTable.
I collect alot of data in my project so i want to show it to the user but i dont know why.

```
self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
        size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
        column_data=[
            ("No.", dp(30)),
            ("Column 1", dp(30)),
            ("Column 2", dp(30)),
            ("Column 3", dp(30)),
            ("Column 4", dp(30)),

        ],
        row_data=[
            
        ],
    )
    return screen
```

This is my database so can somebody help my put the info in the table please.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lT1v.png)

Answer (score 0):

fetch data from your database and pass it to  `row_data` as list.